# No guarda lista python

Tags: python

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de carrito de compra y al pedir que me devuelva la información de la compra no almacena todos los valores ingresados, solo entrega el último valor ingresado.

```
def opc1():
    global lis
    lis=[]
    s="si";
    while(s=="si" or s=="SI"):
        print("---------------Lista de Productos--------------");
        cont=1;
        for i in lis:
            print(cont,".-nombre : ",i[0],"     $",i[1]);
            cont=cont+1
        else:
            nombre=input("Introduzca nombre producto : ");
            valor=int(input("Introduzca valor del producto : "));
            s=input("¿Desea ingresar un nuevo producto? si - no : ");
            lis=lis + [[nombre,valor]]
    ing();
```

El resto del codigo es el siguiente:
Hola gracias por tu respuesta, mi problemas es que al llegar al carrito de compra no almacena todos los item ingresados solo lo ultimo que ingreso.

```
def opc2():
global v;
v=[]
print("");
print("            *****REALIZAR VENTA*****");
print("");
print("---------------Lista de Productos--------------");
cont=1;
f   print("");
nom=int(input("Introduzca numero de producto a comprar : "));
can=int(input("Introduzca cantidada comprar de dicho producto : "));
res=nom-1;
cans=lis[res][1]*can;
print("");
print("--------------------------------------------");
print("");
print("******Carrito de compra*****");
print("");
print("---------------Lista de Productos--------------");
cont=1
print("");
```

y creo que el fallo que tengo se produce en este sección de código:

```
print(cont,".-",lis[res][0],"Cantidad : ",can,"$",cans );
v= [lis[res][0],cans+cans]
print(v);
print("");
print("--Acciones--");
print("");
print("Presione S para seguir comprando");
print("");
print("Presione numero de producto que desea quitar");
print("");
p=input("introduzca opcion de acuerdo cuatro anterior");
if(p=="s" or p=="S"):
    opc2()





ing();
```

[image: cuando se ejecuta no guarda el valor ingresado anteriormente]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El código que proporcionas es correcto. Ten en cuenta que cada vez que llames a `opc1` la variable `lis` pasa a ser una lista vacía porque haces: `lis=[]` al principio de la función. Esto hace que cualquier contenido de `lis` sea borrado cada vez que la ejecutas. Elimina esta línea para que no se borre la lista cada vez que llamas a la función. Si no es este tu problema deberias añadir el resto del código y explicar más detalladamente el problema.

Unas cuantas observaciones por si te interesa:

- Por otro lado, no es necesario usar `;` para terminar una instrucción en Python.
- Puedes usar el método `append` de las listas en vez de concatenar si lo deseas.
- No es necesario usar `global` en este caso.

El código debería ser el siguiente:

```
def opc1():
    s="si"
    while(s=="si" or s=="SI"):
        print("---------------Lista de Productos--------------")
        cont=1
        for i in lis:
            print(cont,".-nombre : ",i[0],"     $",i[1])
            cont=cont+1
        else:
            nombre=input("Introduzca nombre producto : ")
            valor=int(input("Introduzca valor del producto : "))
            s=input("¿Desea ingresar un nuevo producto? si - no : ")
            lis.append([nombre,valor])

    ing()
```

Ejemplo de ejcución:

```
 >>> lis = []
 >>> opc1()

 ---------------Lista de Productos--------------
 Introduzca nombre producto : cebolla
 Introduzca valor del producto : 100
 ¿Desea ingresar un nuevo producto? si - no : si
 ---------------Lista de Productos--------------
 1 .-nombre :  cebolla      $ 100
 Introduzca nombre producto : zanahoria
 Introduzca valor del producto : 200
 ¿Desea ingresar un nuevo producto? si - no : no

 >>> print(lis)
 [['cebolla', 100], ['zanahoria', 200]]

 >>> opc1()

 ---------------Lista de Productos--------------
 1 .-nombre :  cebolla      $ 100
 2 .-nombre :  zanahoria      $ 200
 Introduzca nombre producto : helado
 Introduzca valor del producto : 300
 ¿Desea ingresar un nuevo producto? si - no : no

 print(lis)
 [['cebolla', 100], ['zanahoria', 200], ['helado', 300]]
```